# Which performs better between ref vs id for DOM access?

Tags: performance, vue.js

Which provides better performance when accessing the DOM in vue.

Using ref with $refs or using id with findById?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I imagine, the references to refs are already present in the memory and findById queries the DOM. I'm not entirely sure that this is the case, but it sounds logical, doesn't it?

Comment: Agreed. I can't imagine querying the DOM being faster than a reference to a node.